# Errors setting up federation for rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, federation

I am setting up federation on one rabbitmq broker (B), with another broker as the upstream broker (A).

I'm getting this error on trying to run the command to set up the upstream broker.

```
localhost:$ sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_federation
The following plugins have been enabled:
  rabbitmq_federation
Plugin configuration has changed. Restart RabbitMQ for changes to take effect.

localhost:$ sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_federation_management
The following plugins have been enabled:
  rabbitmq_federation_management

localhost:$ sbin/rabbitmqctl set_parameter federation-upstream my-upstream '{"uri":"amqp://localhost:5672","expires":3600000}'
Setting runtime parameter "my-upstream" for component "federation-upstream" to "{\"uri\":\"amqp://localhost:5672\",\"expires\":3600000}" ...
Error: Validation failed

component federation-upstream not found
```

I did restart the broker after enabling the federation plugins. Why am I getting this error "component federation-upstream not found" ?

I could set up the upstream broker and policy through the Management UI, but federation is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error:

> "validation failed component federation-upstream not found"

which went away after I installed the `rabbitmq_federation` plugin.

Here's my sequence:

1. Installing rabbitmq_federation_management
2. getting error
3. Installing rabbitmq_federation and that cleared the error